# Is it possible to figure out the specifications of an electronics piece without datasheet?

Tags: led, dc-motor, speakers

I'm brand new on the "electrical engineering" scene with my Arduino and I have a question about random electronics. I've been taking apart some old phones, salvaging LEDs, motors and speakers, mostly just for fun. If I were to use these pieces in my own projects is it possible to figure out their specs knowing little to nothing about them? If so, what tools would I need and how would I go about it? What do I need to know to safely integrate them into my own circuits?

Comment: You'll get a feel for a lot of "simpler" parts - for example, the majority of common LEDs all have similar operating ranges, so you don't need to be too picky about the circuit you put it into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on exactly what parts you're trying to characterize. At a minimum, you need a DMM and a variable power supply. The supply should be able to provide, let's say, 12 volts at 1 or 2 amps. It should have both variable voltage and variable current limit settings. Let's take your examples.

LEDs - Set your power supply to 5 volts, short the output, and set the current to 10 mA. The current limit will keep you from burning out most LEDs (although some work on less current), and the voltage should keep you from killing most LEDs if you connect it up backwards.

Motors - Now, this depends on the motor. If it has two leads, it's a brushed DC motor, and you can get an idea of its operation just by hooking it up to your supply, starting at very low voltage. If it has more than 2 leads, you'll need to become familiar with how brushless and stepper motors work, and that is something you need to learn on your own.

Speakers - Measure the coil resistance, then apply a low voltage to the coil by connecting one lead to - on your power supply, then repeatedly touching the positive supply output to the other coil connection, and listening for clicks.

Beyond this, well, first you need to know roughly how the part you're interested in works (if it does work). Then you can figure out a way to test it. For simple components, the tests can usually be pretty simple, but you need to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Using the number of leads to determine the type of motor is not a reliable method.  Plenty of single phase induction motors have 2 leads and motors with integrated controls could have any number of leads.

Comment: True enough. But "I've been taking apart some old phones, salvaging LEDs, motors and speakers" suggests that induction motors and motors with integrated controls are probably not of concern to him.

Comment: I feel a bit silly but just by looking at the battery packs I know that these items are probably at a 3.7 V operating voltage. So that answers the questions for Motors and Speakers. The speakers have a 7/8 Ohm measurement so they must be 8 Ohm speakers. Just read on Instructables how to measure forward voltage of the LEDs with multimeter and variable resistor. So with that information I should be able to hook these components up to a circuit safely right?

Comment: Well, you didn't mention resistors, and cell phones won't have any that you can salvage. If you try to hook up an LED to a battery without a limiting resistor you may well kill the LED. And 3.7 volts across an 8 ohm speaker is probably more than the speaker will handle if left on for too long. Otherwise, sure.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Yeah, sorry I meant now I have all the information I need to calculate the resistance needed for each component. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For simple home-brew circuits component specs don't need to be that precise. Just component experience, looking at it, a multimeter, and maybe a function generator and dc power supply go a long way.

If you want the complete specifications you'd need a huge amount of very expensive T&M equipment, not to mention T&M know-how and that would't even produce all possible data

For example to characterise just a simple two-lead device like a capacitor 'in full':

- Resonant frequency
- Capacitance
- ESR
- ESL
- Leakage resistance
- Maximum working voltage (Destructive test)

You'd at least need a LCR bridge, preferably a Component Analyzer or maybe Network Analyzer and a High Voltage PS to determine the leakage resistance and breakdown voltage.